# Select list with jquery 1.10 behave strange in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, browser

I have create the sample in which based on condition i will set the select list value to new value or previous selected value

**Code sample**

html

```
<select id="my_select">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
my_condition = true;
var lastSel = $("#my_select option:selected");

$("#my_select").change(function(){
  if(my_condition)
  {
    lastSel.attr("selected", true);
      console.log($("#my_select").html());
    console.log($("#my_select option:selected").val());
  }
});

$("#my_select").click(function(){
    lastSel = $("#my_select option:selected");

});
```

above sample working fine with jquery 1.8 but not working with jquery 1.10 only in firefox whereas working well with all jquery version in chrome

1. [fiddle with jquery 1.8.3](http://jsfiddle.net/qk2Pc/595/)
2. [fiddle with jquery 1.10.1](http://jsfiddle.net/qk2Pc/594/)

**Please use firefox standard edition to replicate the problem**

Comment: I don't understand what strange think is there because I found nothing strange?

Comment: Please use firefox standard edition browser .fiddle with jquery 1.8.3 , you cannot select option 2 but with jquery 1.10 you can select option 2. but logic is same ,This is strange!

Comment: ok thanks....You should have mentioned this in your post too.. well never mind